# Is there any connection between Microsoft Graph API user and WindowsIdentity?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I've logged into Windows 10 using my office 365 account and running `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` gives me `AzureAD\\LocTrang` and `Sid`.

When I look into ADSI `CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals` I can see the `Sid`. But pulling down the users from office 365 Azure Active Directory I could not find any correlation between my office 365 account and what `WindowsIdentity` has given me.

I know they're not the same but I need to find the connection between office 365 account and my Windows account which I've logged in using my office 365 account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the attributes used to match users when AAD Connect is run.

AAD Connect syncs AD users up to Azure AD.

Normally UPN is used.

You also need to check what attributes are synched up since if they are not synched, they won't be in Azure AD.

Comment: hmm, not the answer I want to hear as I was suspecting this. I was working locally and I got the Azure AD accounts via Graph API. They're not synced. I was trying to see if there was any connection between my Office 365 AAD and my windows account in which I've logged in with my Office 365 account.

Comment: I assume you have AD? Go to Settings / Accounts / Access work or school and see who you are connected to.